# Looking for a manga, about boy who strictly follows family rules

Tags: story-identification, manga

Looking for a manga about a boy who strictly follows their own family rules. He has a sister who can't walk. And his sister received a transplant for her legs but that made her into a monster?

Does anyone know the title?

Answer (score 1):

This is [Smokin' Parade](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/smokin-parade)

> Youkou lives in a future where organ transplants are common and available to all, but life's not as idyllic as it seems--it turns out a nefarious organization is using that technology for their own evil ends! Only the elite squad Jackalope has any chance of stopping them before it's too late.

The sister's transplant was from this nefarious organization, and the end result is that she turns into a monster and murders her friends in a grotesque manner.

The "family rules" also come up:

[image: Rule 119 - Trash goes in the bin or get a punch to the face]